# Timezone string on client side using moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to deal with time zone related conversions.

I am trying to find out string of timezone such as 'Europe/Berlin' from the timezone offset in the browser.
I am using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` to get timezone offset on the client side.

How can I use this offset to get timezone string `Europe/Berlin` which is the type of format `moment().tz('Europe/Berlin')` expects for conversions.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with moment-timezone.js alone.
In the future you will be able to do `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` as specified in the [ecma script i18n api](http://lindenbergsoftware.com/ecmascript/intl.html#sec-12.3.3) but right now this is only supported by chrome.

If you need crossbrowser support you will have to go with an external library for that job like [jszt](https://github.com/entraigas/jstz) or [tzdetect.js](https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js).